# jQuery Datatable on cell button click get all row cells values

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have the following code for my `jQuery Datatable` where I have a button in the last column. When the user clicks it I need to get all column cell values so I can pass them into a modal for editing.

```
 "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {

                hideWaiting();

                // button to Edit the person
                $('[data-id="btnedit"]').on('click', function (e) {
                    var me = $(this);

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var personId = $(this).attr('data-personid');
                    
                    //*** HERE I WANT TO GET ALL ROW CELLS VALUES ***//

                    $this.showEditModal();
                });

            },
            "aoColumns": [
                { "sName": "Description", "bSortable": true },
                { "sName": "Name", "bSortable": true },
                { "sName": "Position", "bSortable": false },
                { "sName": "ContentUrl", "bSortable": false },
                { "sName": "HolidayType", "bSortable": false },
                { "sName": "LeaveType", "bSortable": false },
                {
                    "mData": null,
                    "bSortable": false,
                    "sWidth": "80px",
                    "sClass": "dt-body-center",
                    "mRender": function (data, type, row) {
                        var res = "";

                        res = '<a href="#" data-id="btnedit" data-personid="' + row[6] + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>';

                        return res;
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this

```
res = '<a href="#" data-id="btnedit" data-personid="' + row[6] + '" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" class="btn-get-row btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>';

$(document).ready( () => {
   $('.btn-get-row').click( (e) => {
      let myCells = $(this).closest('tr').find('td');
      let data = { 
          description: myCells[0].innerHTML,  // or myCells[0].find('input').val();
          name: myCells[1].innerHTML // or myCells[1].find('input').val();
         // ... and so on
      }
   })
})
```